# raw_input in python variable to cmd

Tags: python, cmd, command-prompt

How can I take this code, and take the raw_input and add "ping" before it in cmd, so it'll look like this in command prompt: [ping (raw_input)]

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
          RS_usr = raw_input('input user here: ')
          from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT


          p = Popen(['cmd.exe'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

          out,err = p.communicate(input=RS_usr)
          print(out)
```

Comment: Please remember to accept the best answer to each question by clicking the check mark next to it. You've asked 10 questions and only accepted 2 answers. Please go back and do this for your old, answered questions, too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you should change a couple of lines in your script:

```
p = Popen(['cmd.exe', '/k', 'set PROMPT=[Hello, (' + RS_usr + ')]' ], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

out,err = p.communicate()
```

Comment: so, instead of hello, would I be able to substitute it in cmd for the "ping" command?

Comment: Yes. Note that if you want `ping` to be the *only* command run by `cmd.exe` you should use the `/c` option, rather than `/k`.

Comment: When I run this: `from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT, PIPE ; p = Popen(['cmd.exe', '/c', 'ping www.google.com'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT) ; p.communicate()` with IPython and Python 2.7.2 I get `('\r\nPinging www.l.google.com [209.85.148.106] with 32 bytes of data:\r\nRequest timed out.\r\nRequest timed out.\r\nRequest timed out.\r\nRequest timed out.\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 209.85.148.106:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),\r\n', None)`. You must have something else that doesn't work.